# mouseEntered can't catch fast mouse movement

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse

I have an array of `JToggleButtons` that make a calendar selector of sorts. I have implemented a way to drag the mouse over the buttons to toggle multiple days without having to stop and click each one, and it works great for slower mouse movements:

```
JToggleButton[] buttons = getCalendarDayButtonArray(); //arbitrary instantiation
for (int d = 0; d < 31; d++) {
  final JToggleButton b = new JToggleButton(day);
  buttons[d] = b;
  buttons[d].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//do stuff...}
  }

  buttons[d].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
      if (e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {
        b.doClick();
      }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
      if (e.getModifiers() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) {
        b.doClick();
      }
    }
  });

}
```

However, this doesn't work entirely for quick movements. I am not sure whether it is a problem with the polling rate of the mouse, or a result of any lag on the computer itself, but it seems that the mouse skips over some buttons entirely and as a result the `mouseEntered` method is not invoked for these buttons. Is there a workaround that doesn't involve the user simply moving the mouse slowly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might be easier with a `JList`..

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I would prefer to keep it with `JToggleButton`. The button implementation makes it very quick and easy to select multiple nonconsecutive days/date ranges.

Comment: If you and listen for mouseMoved or mouseDragged on a component you will notice you don't get events for every pixel the mouse moves over the component. So this would be the same problem. I'm guessing you have smaller components to represent each day, so as you move faster over the components the events generated skip some pixels, which results in skipping some components.

Comment: So I would suggest you need to create some kind of interpolation logic.Every time a mouseEntered event is generated you add a component to a List. When more than one component is in the list you need to interpolate the current component with the previous component in the List to see if a component was skipped. On a mouseReleased you would clear the list.

Comment: Also consider a `Set`, which is a "A collection that contains no duplicate elements." You might model your code on the `ListSelectionModel` interface.